# select random cursors on map using selenium ide

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, xpath

I'm using google map api in my site and I want to test the cursors on map using Selenium IDE.
Now I use this code and it works fine:

```
clickAt > xpath=(//map[@id='gmimap85'])
```

but it tests only one cursor (cursor number **85**), and map page is a dynamic page so I want a way to make selenium select any random cursor on map page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want it fully automated you should use WebDriver  But if you dont mind using a specific range of number do a loop using sideflow.js  user Extension for IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a set range but what you can use is:

```
store|javascript{"http://gmimap" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11);}|randomcoord

clickAt|xpath=(//map[@id='${randomcoord}'])|
```

Comment: didn't work :(
please help me more

Comment: cursor details 

map id="gmimap208" name="gmimap208">
<area log="miw" coords="11,0,12,1,13,2,14,3,14,4,14,5,14,6,14,7,14,8,14,9,14,10,13,11,12,12,12,13,11,14,10,15,10,16,9,17,9,18,8,19,7,20,7,20,7,19,6,18,6,17,5,16,4,15,4,14,3,13,2,12,2,11,1,10,1,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,1,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,4,0,11,0" shape="poly" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</map>

Comment: <div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 15px; height: 21px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; left: 373px; top: 370px; z-index: 2000;">
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 15px; height: 21px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="/img/property_icons/free/normal.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap226">
<map id="gmimap226" name="gmimap226">

Comment: hank you everyone for trying help me :) i finally did it

just

|click | //map/area | | 
this command clicks at the first ID cursor in map page :)

Comment: I think we can work on axis path in a map for testing.